# My approach to the Basel Problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In my solution, I did not prove some facts separately (for example identity $\zeta$(2)=$\frac{4}{3}$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$ ) in order to shorten the length of the text. I am asking You to verify my solution in case there are flaws that i didn't notice.

I started by assuming the functtion f(x): $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n}$$
the closed form of f(x) is quite simple, although I will not rigorously prove it, again, in order to shorten the solution $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n}=\frac{\pi -x}{2}$$ for all x $\in (0; \pi]$.
Then we integrate both sides $$\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (nx)}{n} dx = \int \frac{\pi-x}{2}dx$$ $$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos (nx)}{n^2}= \frac{\pi x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4}+C$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos (nx)}{n^2}=\frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{\pi x}{2} - C$$ Now we evaluate it at 1) x=0 and 2) x=$\pi$
$$1)\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = -C$$
$$2)\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{2}-C=-\frac{\pi^2}{4}-C$$
since $\cos(0) = 1$ and $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^n$. Now we subtract 1) from 2) to get the constants of integration cancelled out. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n-1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-2}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{-\pi^2}{4}$$
After dividing by -2 we are left with the closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$ which is equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$. All we are left to do, is to multply it all by $\frac{4}{3}$ to get $$\zeta(2)=\frac{4}{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: People interested in solutions of the Basel problem may find the 14 given at https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf to be of interest.